# Ruby on Rails: one-to-one mapping. Just semantics or really a different structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm creating a plugin for Ruby on Rails to make implemented addresses including country, state, city, and zip_code for countries that can follow that paradigm a lot easier but that's beside the point expect for how the address model is associated.

So starting with my address model.

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :country
    has_one :state
    has_one :city
    has_one :zip_code
end
```

What's the difference between saying  `belongs_to` and `has_one`

Seems to be the same thing because both only require one model to declare ownership and foreign_key

And it also seems that both are logical to say.

> an address belongs to an account and an account has one address

Is this only semantics or is there are real difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ActiveRecord association's perspective, any model with `belongs_to` declaration has the foreign key and any model with `has_one` declaration has the primary key.

If we go by the current state of your model then you have to ensure tables such as `countries`, `sates`, `cities`, and `zip_codes` have a column called `address_id`. Presumably that's not what you want.

So you have to change your `Address` model as follows:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :zip_code
end
```

Which also means you have to ensure `addresses` table has the following columns: `country_id`, `state_id`, `city_id` and `zip_code_id` ( I am assuming this is your current table structure).

**Edit** [I extended my answer to address the questions raised in the comments section.]
In your example you should use `has_many` association rather `has_one` association.

```
class Country
  has_many   :addresses
end

class State
  has_many   :addresses
end

class City
  has_many   :addresses
end

class ZipCode
  has_many   :addresses
end
```

You can make calls such as:

```
country.addresses
state.addresses
city.addresses
zip_code.addresses
```

I have used has_one association in following scenarios.

1) User with a profile

```
 User has one Profile
 Profile belongs to User
```

2) Merchant account with a store

```
 Merchant has one Store     
 Store belongs to Merchant
```

Comment: good call, Actually you wrote exactly what I have. I'm using belongs to. I just wanted to see what others would say.

Comment: oh, I see the difference. But I don't understand the benefit of using has_one?

Comment: Is this so you can call the belongs_to object?

Comment: I have extended my answer to address your comments. Take a look.